# How to map json response with ObjectMapper?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, mapping

I have json response like this

```
{   
  frameData = { 
    eStatus = Active;
    frameId = 12;
    "frame_IMEI" = frrrrr;
    "frame_name" = "EHTPKEIWPR_frrrrr";
    "frame_token" = "";
    "frame_user" = 7;
    "is_frameowner" = 1;
    ownerName = jyoti;
    "owner_picture" = "http";
  };
  message = "Frame added successfully.";
  status = 1;
}
```

I have created model class like this

```
import UIKit
import ObjectMapper

class AddFrameCodeModel: Mappable {

  var status         : Bool?
  var message        : String?
  var frameData      : [FrameDataModel]?


  required init?(_ map: Map) {
    mapping(map)
  }

  func mapping(map: Map) {
    status <- map["status"]
    message <- map["message"]
    frameData <- map["frameData"]

   }

 }

 class FrameDataModel : Mappable {

   var frame_name         : String?
   var eStatus            :String?
   var frame_IMEI     : String?
   var frame_token    : String?
   var frame_user     : String?
   var frameId        : String?
   var is_frameowner  : Bool?
   var ownerName      : String?
   var owner_picture  : String?
   required init?(_ map: Map) {
     mapping(map)
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
     frame_name <- map["frame_name"]
     eStatus <- map["eStatus"]
     is_frameowner <- map["is_frameowner"]
     frame_IMEI <- map["frame_IMEI"]
     frame_token <- map["frame_token"]
     frame_user <- map["frame_user"]
     frameId <- map["frameId"]
     ownerName <- map["ownerName"]
     owner_picture <- map["owner_picture"]
   }
 }
```

But the main problem is that frameData is not mapping because its `[String : Anyobject]` type but i have to convert it into also a model class when i map
 `var frameData      : [String : AnyObject]?`
its success fully mapped but its not convert into model i have to convert it also in model class. My code for mapping is

```
let addFrameCodeData  = Mapper<AddFrameCodeModel>().map(JSONObject)
```

My main problem is that frameData should also be mapped but its not mapping

Please give me you valuable suggestion .

Comment: are you aware that your JSON response is not in a valid format? it is not valid either as a JSON os a JS object

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the brackets from your FrameDataModel type, since its not an array of dictionaries response and do some "custom transforms" as follows https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper.

But I would suggest you to keep the types that the JSON is giving you or set some of it to anyObject and then treat all the casting inside the map function.

I would also create a separated model for "frameData" and treat is as an object.

It is easier to manage and it will be possible to make decoupled changes in the future.

Try this for your json response:

```
import ObjectMapper
```

class AddFrameCodeResponse : Mappable{

```
var status         : Int?
var message        : String?
var frameData      : FrameDataResponse?

required init?(_ map: Map){}

func mapping(map: Map)
{
    status <- map["status"]
    message <- map["message"]
    frameData <- map["frameData"]

}

class FrameDataResponse : Mappable{

    var eStatus = String?
    var frameId = Int?
    var frame_IMEI = String?
    var frame_name = String?
    var frame_token = String
    var frame_user = Int?
    var is_frameowner = Int?
    var ownerName = String?
    var owner_picture = String?

    required init?(_ map: Map){}

    func mapping(map: Map)
    {
        eStatus <- map["eStatus"]
        frameId <- map["frameId"]
        frame_IMEI <- map["frame_IMEI"]
        frame_name <- map["frame_name"]
        frame_token <- map["frame_token"]
        frame_user <- map["frame_user"]
        is_frameowner <- map["is_frameowner"]
        ownerName <- map["ownerName"]
        owner_picture <- map["owner_picture"]

    }
}
```

}

For your frame data Model, try this, and change the types as you need:

import Foundation

class FrameDataModel {

```
let eStatus: String
let id: String
let imei: String
let name: String
let token: String
let user: Int
let isOwner: Int
let ownerName: String
let ownerPicture: String

init(eStatus: String, id: String, imei: String, name: String, token: String, user: Int, isOwner: Int, ownerName: String, ownerPicture: String) {
    self.eStatus = eStatus
    self.id = id
    self.imei = imei
    self.name = name
    self.token = token
    self.user = user
    self.isOwner = isOwner
    self.ownerName = ownerName
    self.ownerPicture = ownerPicture
}
```

}

For your map function, try this:

import Foundation

class JsonResponseToMyClassMapper {
    static func map(jsonResponse: AddFrameCodeResponse) -> (status: String, message: String, frameData: FrameDataModel) {

```
    let status : String = jsonResponse.status!

    let message : String = jsonResponse.message!

    //if you changed the types in the frameDataModel, you will need to cast it here
    let frameData : FrameDataModel = FrameDataModel(eStatus: jsonResponse.message!,
                                          id: jsonResponse.frameId!,
                                        imei: jsonResponse.frame_IMEI!,
                                        name: jsonResponse.frame_name!,
                                        token: jsonResponse.frame_token!,
                                        user: jsonResponse.frame_user!,
                                        isOwner: jsonResponse.is_frameowner!,
                                        ownerName: jsonResponse.ownerName!,
                                        ownerPicture: jsonResponse.owner_picture!)

    return (status, message, frameData)

}
```

}